# TensorFlow weights increasing when using the full dataset for the gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I wrote an article explaining in depth how a neural network works from scratch.

To illustrate the blog post, I wrote the neural network in [python using numpy](https://github.com/theflofly/dnn_from_scratch_py/blob/master/dnn_from_scratch.py) and I wrote a version using [TensorFlow](https://github.com/theflofly/dnn_from_scratch_py/blob/master/dnn_from_scratch_tensorflow.py). I uploaded the code on Github to illustrate this question but this is not a clean version.

The goal of the network is to predict the price of a car based of three of its features (km, type of fuel, age) this is a toy example that I created from scratch.

I retrieved data from the [leboncoin.fr](https://www.leboncoin.fr/), my dataset is composed of around 9k cars (only BMW serie 1). I normalized the data so that the price is between [0, 1], the type of fuel is binary encoded and the age and number of kms are normalized using the mean and standard deviation.

The neural network architecture is really simple and I am using only three car attributes, nonetheless the results of my non tensorflow network are pretty good. The validation test set gives:

```
### Testing summary ###
Iteration: 2000, Loss 0.001066
RMSE: 0.0567967802161
MAE: 0.00757498877216
R2: 0.198448957215
```

I am using the whole dataset during the gradient descent optimization. My problem appears in the TensorFlow version, if I use only 20 inputs during the gradient descent, the loss correctly decreases:

```
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.6057564]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.45724705]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.35986084]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.29016402]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.23823617]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.1986042]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.16779649]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.14347225]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.12400422]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[0.10823684]
```

But if I use the whole dataset, meaning 9k examples, my loss shows an erratic behavior.

```
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[226.40295]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[6130.1694]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[8629.668]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[9219.1445]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[9217.1855]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[9211.8428]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[9209.2715]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[9212.22]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[9204.3613]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[9182.3125]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[9171.9746]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] loss[9200.2207]
```

I don't understand why.

My tensorflow version is the following for now:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

reader = csv.reader(open("normalized_car_features.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",")
x = list(reader)
features = np.array(x[1:]).astype("float")
np.random.shuffle(features)

data_x = features[:, :3]
data_y = features[:, 3:]

m = float(features.shape[0])
threshold = int(m * 0.8)

x_data, x_test = data_x[:threshold, :], data_x[threshold:, :]
y_data, y_test = data_y[:threshold, :], data_y[threshold:, :]

x = tf.placeholder("float")
y = tf.placeholder("float")

w1 = np.matrix([
    [0.01, 0.05, 0.07],
    [0.2, 0.041, 0.11],
    [0.04, 0.56, 0.13]
])

w2 = np.matrix([
    [0.04, 0.78],
    [0.4, 0.45],
    [0.65, 0.23]
])

w3 = np.matrix([
    [0.04],
    [0.41]
])

w1 = tf.Variable(w1, dtype=tf.float32)
w2 = tf.Variable(w2, dtype=tf.float32)
w3 = tf.Variable(w3, dtype=tf.float32)

b1 = tf.Variable(np.matrix([0.1, 0.1, 0.1]), dtype=tf.float32)
b2 = tf.Variable(np.matrix([0.1, 0.1]), dtype=tf.float32)
b3 = tf.Variable(np.matrix([0.1]), dtype=tf.float32)

layer_1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w1), b1))
layer_2 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, w2), b2))
layer_3 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, w3),  b3))

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(layer_3 - y))
loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss], "loss")

train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1/m * 0.01).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    for i in range(10000):
        session.run(train_op, feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data})
```

The predicted values are `[-1, -1, ..., -1, -1]`.

**UPDATE:** with `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1/m * 0.01)` it works as expected.

Comment: It seems that the gradients are not averaged. So with few examples it works.

Comment: apart from all the questions: why do you start off with preset weights? what are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Originally I was using random sample from a normal distribution. I put these weights to confirm that the forward prop was producing the same results as my numpy implementation, and it did. Also when describing the whole concept of weights into my blog post and how they evolve during the forward and backward prop I used these values. It is simpler for the reader to follow along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the Optimizer, it's your loss. It should return the mean loss, not the sum. If you're doing an L2 regression, for instance, it should look like this:

```
l_value = tf.pow(tf.abs(ground_truth - predict), 2) # distance for each individual position of the output matrix of shape = (n_examples, example_data_size)
regression_loss = tf.reduce_sum(l_value, axis=1) # distance per example, shape = (n_examples, 1)
total_regression_loss = tf.reduce_mean(regression_loss) # mean distance of all examples, shape = (1)
```

PS: `tf.abs` is used for convenience, so you can replace the L2 loss for another one (like L1) without having to worry about sign changes, which would yield results in the complex plane.

Comment: My bad (facepalm). Nonetheless in my case, as this is a regression problem, `regression_loss = tf.reduce_sum(l_value, axis=1)` is useless.

Comment: It is useful to have variables for both (reduce_sum and reduce_mean) if you eventually want to evaluate the loss for a single example within the batch. But if you don't care about it, it really isn't necessary. :-)

Comment: Sure, what I was saying is that ground_truth is a `[m x 1]` matrix, `l_value` already gives me the `tf.reduce_sum(l_value, axis=1)` :)

Comment: Well played Micael